# Can punching my iPhone damage it?

Tags: iphone, damage

Sometimes, when I'm suddenly frustrated by something problematic I read on Reddit, I punch my iPhone SE (the 2016 version) screen from a couple inches away using my finger joints while holding it in my other hand (I know, bad habit). I'm wondering whether this bad habit has any risk of causing long-term negative effects to my iPhone, like breaking something on the PCB or damaging the battery.

Comment: If you can't damage your phone by punching it, which seems to be your intention, then I suggest heading to your local boxing gym.  It (boxing) is an excellent way to get and to stay fit, with the added bonus of knowing that next time you punch that sucker it is going to stay punched.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark My intention is not to damage my phone, actually it's the opposite: I don't want to accidentally break something I need to use every day because I'm frustrated. I've been there with 1300 EUR laptops, I don't want to do that again.

Comment: Oh I see.  And on closer reading of your question a solution seems obvious - stay away from sources of annoyance or, as advised below, learn to control your temper better.  And one way of learning to control your temper would be to take up boxing, a sport in which *controlled* aggression is the key to success, and *uncontrolled* aggression the key to finding yourself sitting on the canvas with stars and tweeting birds flying round your head.

Answer (score 3):

Sure it can, just like dropping it on the floor.

999 times you'll get away with it, the 1000th you'll break something.

As this is entirely behavioural rather than accidental, I'd suggest you learn to not do it.